# sql update query with exceptional value

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I want to execute `update query` as

source column is `varchar` type
and target column is `date` type

i am using oracle 10g so isdate function is not working

i want to update column based not rowbased

suppose

expected output after update

```
source             target 
11/12/2012         11 dec 2012 
sdfsdf             null 

update dummy set 
    informationdate = 
(begin to_date(txt_informationdate) exception when others null);
```

i cant use procedure or function that is biggest constraint

Answer (score 0):

This may help [Oracle/PLSQL: To_Date Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)

**EDIT:**

Ok .After reading your question again i think It's probably more efficient to dio a MERGE than an UPDATE in this case.

for more information visit this [Update multiple rows in single column](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1071525)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in a pl/sql context you can really go about it like this

```
declare
   l_date date;
begin
   begin
      l_date := to_date(txt_informationdate);
   exception
      when others then l_date := null;
   end;
   if l_date is null then
      update dummy set informationdate = l_date;
   end if;
exception
   when others then 
      dbms_output.put_line('something else went wrong');
end;
```

I have not tested this, but should work. Maybe you have to correct some syntax errors.

If you want to do that update out of some other language program then you might want to create a little procedure for the above and instead of doing the update to the remote procedure call. Or you could also define yourself a is_date function maybe like this

```
create or replace function is_date(i_date varchar2)
return date
as
begin
   return to_date(i_date);
exception
   when other then return null;
end;
```

Your update might look like this then

```
update dummy set informationdate = is_date(txt_informationdate);
```

Again, that is all untested and might have some syntax errors, but I am sure you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Oracle's error logging facility:

```
execute dbms_errlog.create_error_log('DUMMY', 'DATE_ERRORS');

update dummy 
   set informationdate = to_date(txt_informationdate, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
log errors into date_errors
reject limit unlimited;
```

The update will change all rows where to_date() is successful. All others will be logged into the table DATE_ERRORS you can inspect them there.

Note that I used a format mask in the to_update() call to ensure that the text is converted correctly. You should never use to_date() without specifying a format because that relies on NLS (client) settings which might not be the way you think they are.